# Container runtime network not ready: cni config uninitialized

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, cni

I'm installing kubernetes(kubeadm) on centos VM running inside `Virtualbox`, so with yum I installed `kubeadm, kubelet` and `docker`.

Now while trying to setup cluster with `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.56.0/24 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.33/32` i run into the following error :

```
Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d

Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

So I checked, no `cni` folder in `/etc` even that `kubernetes-cni-0.6.0-0.x86_64` is installed. I Tried commenting `KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS` in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` but it didn't work.

PS:

- I'm installing behind proxy.
- I have multiple network adapters:

  - NAT : 10.0.2.15/24 for Internet
  - Host Only : 192.168.56.33/32
  - And docker interface : 172.17.0.1/16

> Docker version:  17.12.1-ce
>   kubectl version : Major:"1",
>   Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.3"
>   Centos 7

Answer (score 35):

Add pod network add-on - Weave Net

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/releases/download/v2.8.1/weave-daemonset-k8s.yaml
```

Comment: if the above calico doesn't work then go to the link
https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/master/manifests/calico.yaml

copy and paste it into a new calico file and apply it
it should work

Answer (score 19):

Stop and disable apparmor & restart the containerd service on that node will solve your issue

```
root@node:~# systemctl stop apparmor
root@node:~# systemctl disable apparmor 
root@node:~# systemctl restart containerd.service
```

Comment: This, this one works. tnx.

Comment: thanks this unlocked it, -- kubeadm 1.26.3 Calico CNI Containerd Docker.io -- 
Would be great to know the reason why.

Comment: This did it for me. kubernetesVersion 1.27.3 using flannel. Followed by a systemctl restart kubelet.

Comment: @setrar AppArmor is a Linux kernel security module that allows the system administrator to restrict programs' capabilities with per-program profiles. Profiles can allow capabilities like network access, raw socket access, and the permission to read, write, or execute files on matching paths, need to configure AppArmor if you want to allow k8s services

Comment: restart containerd.service it works for me

Comment: now the 4th time Im here :) what does apparmor have to do with containerd?

Comment: If you are using RKE2, you should restart rke server instead of contained: systemctl restart rke2-server.service

Answer (score 13):

There are several points to remember when setting up the cluster with "kubeadm init" and it is clearly documented on the Kubernetes site [kubeadm cluster create](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/):

- "kubeadm reset" if you have already created a previous cluster
- Remove the ".kube" folder from the home or root directory
- (Also stopping the kubelet with systemctl will allow for a smooth setup)
- Disable swap permanently on the machine, especially if you are rebooting your linux system
- And not to forget, install [a pod network add-on](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) according to the instructions provided on the add on site (not Kubernetes site)
- Follow the post initialization steps given on the command window by kubeadm.

If all these steps are followed correctly then your cluster will run properly.

And don't forget to do the following command to enable scheduling on the created cluster:

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

About how to install from behind proxy you may find this useful:

[install using proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580788/how-to-install-kubernetes-cluster-behind-proxy-with-kubeadm)

Answer (score 6):

Check [this answer](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48798#issuecomment-427454190).

> Use this PR (till will be approved):
>
> `kubectl -n kube-system apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`
>
> it's a known issue: [coreos/flannel#1044](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/1044)

Answer (score 5):

I could not see the helm server version:

```
$ helm version --tiller-namespace digital-ocean-namespace
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.1", GitCommit:"618447cbf203d147601b4b9bd7f8c37a5d39fbb4", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: could not find a ready tiller pod
```

The `kubectl describe node kubernetes-master --namespace digital-ocean-namespace` command was showing the message:

```
NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

The nodes was not ready:

```
$ kubectl get node --namespace digital-ocean-namespace
NAME                  STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
kubernetes-master     NotReady   master   82m   v1.14.1
kubernetes-worker-1   NotReady   <none>   81m   v1.14.1
```

I had a version compatibility issue between Kubernetes and the flannel network.

My k8s version was `1.14` as seen in the command:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:02:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

After re-installing the flannel network with the command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

I could then see the helm server version:

```
$ helm version --tiller-namespace digital-ocean-namespace
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.1", GitCommit:"618447cbf203d147601b4b9bd7f8c37a5d39fbb4", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.1", GitCommit:"618447cbf203d147601b4b9bd7f8c37a5d39fbb4", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Comment: kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

this worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Resolved this issue by installing Calico CNI plugin using following commands:

```
curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml -O
kubectl apply -f calico.yaml
```

Comment: for me the above calico worked till kubernetes version v1.25.4.
for the newer versions i used the below  link

https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/master/manifests/calico.yaml ...

copy and pasted it in the new  calico file and applied it.
it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by Installing a Pod network add-o,
I used Flannel pod network which is a very simple overlay network that satisfies the kubernetes requirements

you can do it with this command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

You can read more about this in the kubernetes documentation

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network

Answer (score 2):

It was a proxy error as mentionned in `Github` https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34695

They suggested to use `kubeadm init --use-kubernetes-version v1.4.1` but i change my network entirely (no proxy) and i manage to setup my cluster.

After that we can setup pod network with `kubectl apply -f ...` see https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network

Answer (score 1):

I face the same errors and it seens that It seens that `systemd` have a problems. I'm not remember my last `systemd` version. But update it solve the problems for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same errors, I was seeing the issue after slave node joined to cluster. Slave node was showing status 'Not ready' after joining.

I checked `kubectl describe node ksalve` and observed the mentioned issue.
After digging deeper I found that `systemd` was different in master and slave node.
In master I have configured `systemd` however slave has default `cfgroup` only.

Once I removed the `systemd` from master node, slave status immediately changed to `Ready`.

Comment: Can you elaborate > I removed the systemd from master node

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was updating the hostname after the cluster was created. By doing that, it's like the master didn't know it was the master.

I am still running:

`sudo hostname $(curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname)` [[1](https://www.nebulaworks.com/blog/2019/08/27/leveraging-aws-ebs-for-kubernetes-persistent-volumes/)][[2](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/668#issuecomment-378697007)]

but now I run it before the cluster initialization

Error that lead me to this from running `sudo journalctl -u kubelet`:

```
Unable to register node "ip-10-126-121-125.ec2.internal" with API server: nodes "ip-10-126-121-125.ec2.internal" is forbidden: node "ip-10-126-121-125" cannot modify node "ip-10-126-121-125.ec2.internal"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is because I forgot to open the `8285` port. `8285` port is used by flannel you need to open it from the firewall.

e.g:
if you use flannel addon and your OS is centOS:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8285/tcp 
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I restarted docker and the status changed to ready

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Answer (score -3):

This is for AWS VPC CNI

1. Step1 : kubectl get mutatingwebhookconfigurations -oyaml >
   mutating.txt
2. Step 2: Kubectl delete -f mutating.txt
3. Step3: Restart the node
4. Step4 : You should be able to see the node is ready
5. Step5: Install the mutatingwebhookconfiguration back