# I'm trying to create High Available master node but getting Exception in cni Plugin

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, amazon-elb

I have created one ec2 instance and added that to loadbalancer
while I try to create master node with `kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "LOAD_BALANCER_DNS:LOAD_BALANCER_PORT" --upload-certs`
command I'm getting following logs `from kubelet status`

> kubelet[11586]: E0305 06:48:26.280438   11586 kubelet.go:2183] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready cni config uninitialized

When I tried to install CNI plugin it shows

> Are you using correct host or port?

Can someone help me to resolve this

Comment: Are you using EKS here?

Comment: No I'm trying with kubeadm tool

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112336/container-runtime-network-not-ready-cni-config-uninitialized)?

Comment: No will check now

Comment: But If I give kubeadm init the node is created,If I create with loadbalancer ip and port it is not getting created after creation only  i can make the following steps right?       mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
 sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
 sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

Comment: Have you replaced `"LOAD_BALANCER_DNS:LOAD_BALANCER_PORT"` with a proper values? Are you sure you created the load balancer for kube-apiserver as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/#create-load-balancer-for-kube-apiserver)?

Comment: yes i have given proper values as given in the documentation

Comment: Looks like you are missing the CNI. Take a look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network). Basically you need to specify '--pod-network-cidr' with the `kubeadm init`. You have to chose one. Usually Flannel is a safe option.

Comment: @OhHiMark yes I didn't configured properly

Comment: Now working thanks

Comment: @HARININATHAN What have you done exactly? Have you used my advice or did something else? Please explain.

Comment: yes i followed your advise and now it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready cni config uninitialized` means that your CNI is misconfigured or missing.

In order to make it work properly you need to specify `--pod-network-cidr` while executing the `kubeadm init` command.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) you can find the official documentation with a list of most popular Pod network plugins to choose from like Calico or Flannel.