# Couldn't proceed with upgrade process as new nodes are not joining node group standard-workers

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to upgrade my kubernetes version from `1.14` to `1.15`, the cluster upgrade went well but when i am trying to update the node i am seeing the message
`Couldn't proceed with upgrade process as new nodes are not joining node group standard-workers . I had created the nodes using eksctl`.

I see the following error when i check the new node details under workloads.

```
runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

I also checked the tags associated with the new nodes getting spun up, they are all the same with one difference, the existing nodes have `aws:ec2launchtemplate:version` set to `1` and new nodes have it set to `4`

I have checked the CNI plugin version and it corresponds to the latest once recommened

```
kubectl describe daemonset aws-node --namespace kube-system | grep Image | cut -d "/" -f 2
amazon-k8s-cni-init:v1.7.5-eksbuild.1
amazon-k8s-cni:v1.7.5-eksbuild.1
```

Any help on how to get around this would be really helpfull.

TIA

Comment: Did you take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112336/container-runtime-network-not-ready-cni-config-uninitialized https://dzone.com/articles/upgrading-kubernetes-worker-nodes-in-gke-aks-and-e https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/306 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for others visiting the post. I found out that the issue was the `url` i was using to configure the kube proxy.

As per the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/update-cluster.html, it says

```
Update kube-proxy to the recommended version by taking the output from the 
previous step and replacing the version tag with your cluster's recommended
 kube-proxy version:


kubectl set image daemonset.apps/kube-proxy \
    -n kube-system \
    kube-proxy=<602401143452.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com>/eks/kube-proxy:v<1.18.9>-eksbuild.1

Your account ID and Region may differ from the example above.
```

I misunderstood the last part of account id and substituted it with my account id, which resulted in the image not getting found.

After using the correct link with account id `602401143452`, i was able to fix the issue and node group upgrade was successful.

Hope this helps, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to update you CNI version. Please follow the CNI upgrade tutorial from here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-upgrades.html