# Error while creating node group in aws kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

I have created an EKS cluster successfully, but while adding a node I am getting the following error-

```
runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

I am not getting any clue how to rid of this error.

Additional details -
Region- us-east-1
Kubernetes Version - 1.20

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Container runtime network not ready: cni config uninitialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112336/container-runtime-network-not-ready-cni-config-uninitialized)

Comment: Do you use a Pod network add-on? If so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

Before creating a node group need to create a CNI role for your cluster.
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html#gs-console-oidc ("Managed nodes – Linux" part, "To create your Amazon EC2 Linux managed node group" topic). Please note that this role is unique for each EKS cluster since it depends from OpenID Connect provider info. Steps 1-3 (from this topic) execution should solve your issue.