# Kubernetes : do we need to set http_proxy and no_proxy in apiserver manifest?

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, http-proxy, kubeadm

My cluster is behind a corporate proxy, and I have manually set `http_proxy=myproxy`, `https_proxy=myproxy` and `no_proxy=10.96.0.0/16,10.244.0.0/16,<nodes-ip-range>` in the three kubernetes core manifests (*kube-apiserver.yaml*, *kube-controller-manager.yaml* and *kube-scheduler.yaml*). Now, I want to upgrade kubernetes with kubeadm. But I know kubeadm will regenerate these manifests from the kubeadm-config configmap when upgrading, so without these environment variables. I can't find an `extraEnvs` key in kubeadm-config configmap (like `extraArgs` and `extraVolumes`).

Do I really need to set these variables in all kubernetes manifests ? If not, I think kubeadm will throw a warning because all communications will use the proxy (and I don't want that).

How can I pass these variables to kubeadm when upgrading ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such a flags available for Kubeadm at the moment. You may want to open github request for that feature.

You can use the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580788/how-to-install-kubernetes-cluster-behind-proxy-with-kubeadm) or [here](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/kubeadm/) and export variables:

```sh
$ export http_proxy=http://proxy-ip:port/
$ export https_proxy=http://proxy-ip:port/
$ export no_proxy=master-ip,node-ip,127.0.0.1
```

And then use `sudo -E bash` to use the current

```sh
$ sudo -E bash -c "kubeadm init... "
```

---

Alternative way would be to reference those variables in the command as showed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2145#issuecomment-630271283):

```sh
NO_PROXY=master-ip,node-ip,127.0.0.1 HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy-ip:port/ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16...
```